# jQuery: how to access certain values within an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I am new to arrays in jQuery. 
If I have an array that looks as follows, is there a way that I can access just the numbers (without the item names) ?

I would to extract the group of numbers for each item, so instead of "item1: 5, 7, 9" I would need just "5, 7, 9" etc.

```
var arr = 
{
    item1: 5, 7, 9
    item2: 3, 5, 3
    item3: 1, 7, 5
    //...
}
```

Comment: That's not an array.  It's an object.  That's also not even valid JavaScript syntax.  What *exactly* do you have?  Does `arr.item1` work for you?

Comment: It would be a valid Javascript syntax if items are arrays: `item1: [5, 7, 9]` and so on...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it looks like Justin's example - sorry, I typed that wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid syntax:

```
var arr = 
{
    item1: [5, 7, 9],
    item2: [3, 5, 3],
    item3: [1, 7, 5]
}
```

Calling `arr.item1` will give you back an array: `item1`.
Since `arr` is an object, you can access its items (keys) like properties.

If you want first number from that array, you can use `arr.item1[0]`.
In a more dynamic way, you could use `each`:

```
$.each(arr.item1, function(key, value) 
{
   console.log('item1 contains number ' + value);
});
```

Output:

```
item1 contains number 5
item1 contains number 7
item1 contains number 9
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
var arr = 
{
    "item1": [5, 7, 9],
    "item2": [3, 5, 3],
    "item3": [1, 7, 5]
}
```

And you can access it with `arr["item1"]` and that will return `[5,7,9]`.

You could also do it as:

```
var arr = 
[
    [5, 7, 9],
    [3, 5, 3],
    [1, 7, 5]
]
```

And access it as `arr[0]` with a return of `[5,7,9]`